# Adicionar filtro no ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2, filtro

É possível adicionar selectInput no ggplot2?
A minha ideia seria filtrar por `ano` o faturamento dos técnicos para que o gráfico não ficasse da forma como está, o que dexaria mais organizado ao filtrar por `ano` pois mostraria apenas os técnicos que trabalhavam naquele `ano` com o seu respectivo faturamento.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
dados1 <- read_excel("fat_tecnico.xlsx")
dados1$Ano <- as.character(dados1$Ano)


ggplot(dados1, aes(x = Técnico, y = Total, fill = Ano, label = Total)) +
  aes(x = reorder(Técnico, Total), y = Total) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  selectInput("Ano", label = "Ano: ", choices = unique(dados1$Ano), selected = "2015") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 450000, 50000)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Total), hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5, size = 3L) +
  labs(title = "Faturamento de Serviços por Técnico (2015-2021*)",
       x = "Técnicos",
       y = "Faturamento (R$)",
       fill = "Ano") +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: É possível, mas o selectInput estaria em uma aplicação Shiny

Comment: Olá, Vinícius. Utilizei o pacote plotly, com a função ggplotly...isso permitiu com que quando eu apertasse em um dos anos o filtro fosse aplicado...o problema depois foi tentar ajustar as espessuras das barras pois elas ficaram muito desproporcional...

Comment: Entendi, eu já tive muita dificuldade no passado usando o ggplotly, pois dependendo do que se fez no ggplot2 acaba se perdendo, talvez o uso das funções do plotly para construir o gráfico do zero funcionem melhor

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma seria você gerar os gráficos para cada ano, utilizando a função `facet_wrap()` do `ggplot2` ([consulte a documentação](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html)).

O trecho de código abaixo ilustra como fazer isto.

```r
## Carregando os pacotes utilizados
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


# Gerando base de dados para o exemplo
dados <- tibble::tibble(
  tecnico = rep(
    c("Ana", "Joaquim", "Maria",
      "José", "Renato", "Andre", "Marcos"), 7),
  ano = rep(2015:2021, each = 7),
  faturamento = runif(7*7, min = 1000, max = 50000)
)

# Gerando os gráficos por ano
ggplot(
  data = dados,
  mapping = aes(
    x = tecnico,
    y = faturamento
  )
) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~ ano, scales = "free", ncol = 2) +
  geom_text(
    mapping = aes(label = round(faturamento, digits = 2)), 
    size = 3
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Faturamento de Serviços por Técnico (2015-2021*)",
    x = "Técnicos",
    y = "Faturamento (R$)"
  ) +  
  coord_flip()
```

[Exemplo do gráfico gerado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNV6I.png)